# How do I see if two characters are separated in a specific way in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, charat

I'm doing a coding challenge on coderbyte in javascript. Here is the question: 
Using the JavaScript language, have the function ABCheck(str) take the str parameter being passed and return the string true if the characters a and b are separated by exactly 3 places anywhere in the string at least once (ie. "lane borrowed" would result in true because there is exactly three characters between a and b). Otherwise return the string false.

Here is my proposed answer which isn't working. I can't figure out why... In a lot of the answers people are converting the string to an array but is there a way to do this with .charAt()? Thanks!

```
function ABCheck(str) {
    for (var i=0; i < str.length-4; i++){
        if ((str.charAt(i) == "a") && (str.charAt(i+4) == "b")){
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

I've corrected the string vs str mixup and the "-4" after the str.length. I'm still getting problems with the following cases. "after it", "aaaaddddd", and "123advb. They should all be false. How do I do this? Thanks again.

Comment: `str != string` that's the issue.

Comment: also `i < str.length - 4`, or else `string.charAt(i + 4)` would return  a `outofboundsexception` error.

Comment: One question - does order of a and b matter?  As I read the question, both "a123b" and "b123a" should return true.  Second question: why not use a regex?

Comment: Honestly, regex is a little beyond my level right now...

Comment: After the end of your loop you need a  `return false;`  Otherwise I don't know what Javascript will return, its one of those obscure mysteries that make JS so interesting.

Comment: p.s. that's a (pood) attempt at a pun on "undefined"

Comment: I appreciate puns of any kind, poor or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you could also use regex. This is assuming the b always follows a.

```
function ABCheck(str)
{
    return str.match(/a...b/g) != null;
}
```

Comment: This may be a better solution, but it doesn't answer the question of why the OP's code isn't working. `/regex/.test(str)` is better than `str.match(/regex/)` because it already returns a boolean. The `/g` global match isn't necessary because you don't care about all matches, only whether or not there is any match.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work somewhat OK, you just have a typo:

`string.charAt(i+4)` should be `str.charAt(i+4)`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/UE5rS/

Comment: Need to check for an OOB exception, no?

Comment: Yep, agreed, but the initial problem was that the method was broken entirely due to the issue above (but on second thought, outofbounds doesn't seem to be an issue with this method, based on some tests - try the fiddle).